# Converting BMP into grayscale using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a BMP image into gray-scale using python. Here is the proper question.

> Write a program that edits an image file, turning it into grayscale.
>   Replace each pixel with a pixel that has the same grayness level for
>   the blue, green, and red component. The grayness level is computed by
>   adding 30 percent of the red level, 59 percent of the green level, and
>   11 percent of the blue level. (The color-sensing cone cells in the
>   human eye differ in their sensitivity for red, green, and blue light.)

I have done some coding but it is not actually turning into gray-scale but more or less into a concoction of strange colors. Can someone please correct my code and see what I am doing wrong? Here is my code

```
from io import SEEK_CUR
def main():
    filename = input("Please enter the file name: ")

    # Open as a binary file for reading and writing
    imgFile = open(filename, "rb+")

    # Extract the image information.
    fileSize = readInt(imgFile, 2)
    start = readInt(imgFile, 10)
    width = readInt(imgFile, 18)
    height = readInt(imgFile, 22)

    # Scan lines must occupy multiples of four bytes.
    scanlineSize = width * 3
    if scanlineSize % 4 == 0:
        padding = 0
    else :
        padding = 4 - scanlineSize % 4

    # Make sure this is a valid image.
    if fileSize != (start + (scanlineSize + padding) * height):
        exit("Not a 24-bit true color image file.")

    # Move to the first pixel in the image.
    imgFile.seek(start)# Process the individual pixels.
    for row in range(height): #For each scan line
        for col in range(width): #For each pixel in the line
            processPixel(imgFile)

        # Skip the padding at the end.
        imgFile.seek(padding, SEEK_CUR)

    imgFile.close()## Processes an individual pixel.#@param imgFile the binary file containing the BMP image#

def processPixel(imgFile): #Read the pixel as individual bytes.
    theBytes = imgFile.read(3)
    blue = theBytes[0]
    green = theBytes[1]
    red = theBytes[2]

    # Process the pixel.
    newBlue = 255 - blue
    newGreen = 255 - green
    newRed = 255 - red

    # Write the pixel.
    imgFile.seek(-3, SEEK_CUR)# Go back 3 bytes to the start of the pixel.
    imgFile.write(bytes([newBlue, newGreen, newRed]))## Gets an integer from a binary file.#@param imgFile the file#@ param offset the offset at which to read the integer#@


def readInt(imgFile, offset): #Move the file pointer to the given byte within the file.
    imgFile.seek(offset)

    # Read the 4 individual bytes and build an integer.
    theBytes = imgFile.read(4)
    result = 0
    base = 1
    for i in range(4):
        result = result + theBytes[i] * base
        base = base * 256

    return result# Start the program.
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line here

```
imgFile.write(bytes([newBlue, newGreen, newRed]))
```

Lets have a look at what `bytes` does

```
In [1]: ?bytes
Type:        type
String form: <type 'str'>
Namespace:   Python builtin
Docstring:
str(object='') -> string

Return a nice string representation of the object.
If the argument is a string, the return value is the same object.

In [2]: bytes(10)
Out[2]: '10'

In [3]: bytes([10,9])
Out[3]: '[10, 9]'
```

As you can see, it doesn't appear to be doing what you think it should be.

You're looking for the `bytearray` class

```
In [4]: ?bytearray
Type:        type
String form: <type 'bytearray'>
Namespace:   Python builtin
Docstring:
bytearray(iterable_of_ints) -> bytearray.
bytearray(string, encoding[, errors]) -> bytearray.
bytearray(bytes_or_bytearray) -> mutable copy of bytes_or_bytearray.
bytearray(memory_view) -> bytearray.

Construct an mutable bytearray object from:
  - an iterable yielding integers in range(256)
  - a text string encoded using the specified encoding
  - a bytes or a bytearray object
  - any object implementing the buffer API.

bytearray(int) -> bytearray.

Construct a zero-initialized bytearray of the given length.

In [5]: bytearray([1,2,3])
Out[5]: bytearray(b'\x01\x02\x03')
```

Comment: How would I implement that into the code and then add 30 percent of the red level, 59 percent of the green level, and 11 percent of the blue level.?

Comment: So, adding `30%` of something is the same as multiplying it by `1.3`. In python, if you multiply a float and an int, you will end up with a float, so you will need to use the `int` function to make it `bytearray`-able again, e.g. `newRed = int(red*1.3)`. You'll also want to make sure that you do not exceed 256 as `bytearray` will complain.

Comment: Can you please add that to my code. I am still not sure how to change bytes to bytearray

Comment: So this line: `imgFile.write(bytes([newBlue, newGreen, newRed]))` should use `bytearray` instead of `bytes`

Comment: Thank you. Shouldn't 30% be 0.3?

Comment: Multiplying by `0.3` means "take 30%, multiplying by `1.3` means "take 30%, and add it to the original"

Comment: This is what I did

`newBlue = int(blue*1.11)
    newGreen = int(green*1.59)
    newRed = int(red*1.3)`

and I got the error `imgFile.write(bytearray([newBlue, newGreen, newRed]))## Gets an integer from a binary file.#@param imgFile the file#@ param offset the offset at which to read the integer#@
ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)`

Comment: I mentioned that you should check to make sure your new values did not exceed 255. If they do, set them to 255.

Comment: Yes I saw that. So should I just set them to 255? I was told to specifically add the said percentages to the colors.

Comment: I've done some googling, and it seems your problem statement is a bit misleading. You aren't supposed to add that much to each color, you need to produce a weighted average with that much of each color. Read http://www.had2know.com/technology/rgb-to-gray-scale-converter.html for an explanation.

Comment: I will. Te question is straight out if a book though.

Answer (score 0):

```
In this area of your code:

def processPixel(imgFile): #Read the pixel as individual bytes.
    theBytes = imgFile.read(3)
    blue = theBytes[0]
    green = theBytes[1]
    red = theBytes[2]
#ADD THIS LINE OF CODE
    gray = int((0.2126*red)+(0.7152*green)+(0.0722*blue))
    # Process the pixel.
#CHANGE IT TO THE FOLLOWING COLORS BY SUBTRACTING THE "gray" from 255
    newBlue = 255 - gray
    newGreen = 255 - gray
    newRed = 255 - gray
```